# Is it possible to declare a matrix as a derived type in Fortran?

Tags: oop, fortran, fortran2003, derived-types

Is it possible to declare a matrix as a derived type in Fortran? For example, can something be done so that the call

```
class(four_by_four_matrix) :: A

call A%inv
```

is valid? Where `inv` is declared as a procedure of `four_by_four_matrix`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question "is it possible?" is yes, it is possible. Just put a 2d array into your type:

```
  type four_by_four_matrix
    real(rp) :: arr(4,4)
  contains
    procedure :: inv => four_by_four_matrix_inv
  end type

contains

  subroutine four_by_four_matrix_inv(self)
    class(four_by_four_matrix), intent(inout) :: self
    ....
    !somehow invert self%arr
  end subroutine

end module

...

type(four_by_four_matrix) :: A

call A%inv
```

If you need more details, you have to make a question with your actual detailed problems.

BTW type-bound procedures and the `class` keyword were introduced in Fortran 2003. Notice you don't necessarily need to use `class`, you can also use `type(four_by_four_matrix)` if your variable is not polymorphic.

Answer (score 3):

Vladimir F gives [an approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36260435) using type-bound procedures introduced in Fortran 2003, and also comments on the polymorphic declaration of `class`.

That answer assumes you have, as the question suggests, a four-by-four matrix, or at least a size known when compiling.  In wider use one may want to generalize.  Of value then would be making the component array allocatable (ensuring that it is somehow allocated and noting this isn't Fortran 90/95 either).

Alternatively, Fortran 2003 also introduced the concept of *parameterized* derived types.  Here, much like the idea of length in a character variable one could have a length-parameterized derived type:

```
type square_matrix(n)
  integer, len :: n
  real matrix(n,n)
end type square_matrix
```

declaring variables like

```
type(square_matrix(4)) A  ! Like type(four_by_four_matrix), perhaps
type(square_matrix(8)) B  ! Like type(eight_by_eight_matrix), perhaps
```

One can even have deferred-length variables of this type

```
type(square_matrix(:)), allocatable :: A, B
integer q
q = ... ! Something run-time, perhaps.
allocate(square_matrix(q) :: A)
B = square_matrix(q)(matrix)  ! Constructor using a matrix value
```

The type-bound procedure acts on an arbitrary parameterized type, using assumed-length syntax:

```
subroutine inv(sm)
  class(square_matrix(*)), intent(inout) :: sm
  ...
end subroutine inv
```

An almost complete example would be as follows.

```
module matrix_mod

  implicit none

  type square_matrix(n)
    integer, len :: n
    real matrix(n,n)
   contains
    procedure inv
  end type square_matrix

contains

  subroutine inv(sm)
    class(square_matrix(*)), intent(inout) :: sm
    ! Some inv stuff, but as a placeholder
    print '("Called inv with a ",I0,"-by-",I0," matrix")', sm%n, sm%n
  end subroutine inv

end module matrix_mod

  use matrix_mod
  implicit none

  type(square_matrix(4)) A

! Establish A%matrix somehow, perhaps with a structure constructor
  call A%inv()

end
```

Naturally, one isn't restricted to square matrices: multiple parameters can be used.  Further, I've also skipped over the possibility of kind-parameterization.

Comment: I was thinking about writing about that, as it is quite natural for this usage. But I am still not ready to use this in practice, because the gfortran's support is still  not available in the versions most people use.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that there was support even in most recent gfortran versions (but I don't keep up on that), so yes, this is an answer for the future and the wider audience.  There are few examples on this site of PDTs, perhaps because of limited compiler support, and this seems a simple and natural case.