# Create a user defined type that depends on one of its element

Tags: types, fortran, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to define a user defined type that one of its elements depends on another. This is a test code that summarises the way I tried;

```
module def
  type vector
    integer, parameter :: long
    real,dimension(1:long) :: vec
  end type vector
end module def

program main
  use def
  implicit none

  type(vector) :: y
  y%long = 2
  y%vec = (/1.0d0, 2.0d0/)

  print*, y

end program main
```

But it seems that it can't be done in this way, because when I compile it in `gfortran`, I have the following error:

```
integer, parameter :: long
                  1
Error: Attribute at (1) is not allowed in a TYPE definition
testmodule.f03:4:17:
```

How should this be done?

Comment: You're looking for Fortran's *parameterized derived types*.  It's a recent feature that not all compilers in common use, not even the latest versions thereof, have yet implemented.  Use your search engine, there may even be a question or two about them hereabouts.

Comment: One example being [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52663082/3157076).

Comment: Your question resembles very much [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090715/fortran-array-of-unknown-size-in-type), and you should also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36263517/2938526) to another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How should this be done?

In fact, there is a pretty direct response to this question: *parameterized derived type*.

@HighPerformanceMark is right in saying that today (2019), despite this feature having been presented in a standard 16 years ago, it was barely and lately covered by compilers.

Although, and in fact this is the reason I decided to write this answer despite some existing questions about this matter, I want leave aside the controversy around this feature and present a sharp, ultimate suggestion: **USE IT**.

There are [at least 5](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Fortran+2003+status) major compilers that implemented this feature today (Cray, GNU, IBM, Intel, PGI). Most of them still have bugs, but they **need** to be used and, therefore, tested. Then, when/if you find a bug, please report to the vendor. Only this way this feature will break the *stigma* created over it and become popular.

I know we all have serious business to do and don't have time to spend with "fancy new untested stuff" and want proven, efficient, mathematically sensible solutions. That is why we chose Fortran, after all. I wouldn't had recommended it for this people (us) a few years ago, but now most implementations reached a level of usability that worths the bet, and the usage is the only way to trim the rough edges.

Parameterized derived types translate, intuitively, the real problem you described. It provides an automatic (and elegant) way to model the domain of the type, considering math and programming aspects at once. The correct syntax for your program is:

```
module def
  type vector(long)
    integer, len :: long
    real, dimension(long) :: vec
  end type vector
end module def

program main
  use def
  implicit none

  type(vector(2)) :: y
  y%vec = [1.0, 2.0]

  print*, y

end program main
```

You can find more information about it [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-parameterized-type-statements) and also all over the internet, or in you favorite *Modern Fortran* book.